# Using an open source LLM in SQL Chain

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, langchain

Is it possible to use open source LLM models in SQL chain ?
I have tried using tapex/Flan models in SQL Chain, but getting a serialization error on dict[] classes.

Error:

```
File "pydantic\main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.init
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for SQLDatabaseChain
root -> llm
value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

sample snippet

```
tokenizer = TapexTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/tapex-base-finetuned-wtq")
model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("microsoft/tapex-base-finetuned-wtq")
chain = SQLDatabaseChain(llm=model, database=db, verbose=True)
chain.run("context query ?")
```

Are there any samples/snippets are available for using open source LLM models in SQL Chain ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the sql query yourself by describing the database and example data in a template?
Then create a sequential or multi-chain to verify the sql query works and then perform the query yourself use SQL Agent or psycog2?

Answer (score 0):

```
    db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/db_name?connect_timeout=10&target_session_attrs=primary",
                                  include_tables=['table_name'])
    chain = SQLDatabaseChain(llm=CustomLLM(), database=db, verbose=True)
    chain.run("How many users are there?")
        
    class CustomLLM(LLM):
        model_name = "microsoft/tapex-base-finetuned-wtq"
        tokenizer = TapexTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/tapex-base-finetuned-wtq")
        streamer = TextStreamer(tokenizer, skip_prompt=True, skip_special_tokens=True)
        model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("microsoft/tapex-base-finetuned-wtq")
    
        def _call(self, prompt, stop=None, **kwargs):
            prompt = f"### User:\n{prompt}\n\n### Assistant:\n"
            inputs = self.tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt").to(self.model.device)
            output = self.model.generate(**inputs, streamer=self.streamer, use_cache=True, max_new_tokens=float('inf'))
            return self.tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    
        @property
        def _identifying_params(self):
            return {"name_of_model": self.model_name}
    
        @property
        def _llm_type(self):
            return "custom"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**This is an example of using LLM (In this example: codellama-13b-instruct.gguf) from local directory in SQL Chain in Langchain Library**

Reference Link : https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/qa_structured/sql

```
# @author: prgarg007

from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain.utilities import SQLDatabase
from langchain.chains import create_sql_query_chain
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])
llm = LlamaCpp(
    model_path = "codellama-13b-instruct.gguf",
    temperature = 0.0,
    n_ctx=10000,
    n_gpu_layers= 15, # Change this until this crash (This is for offloading to GPU)
    n_threads = 3,
    n_batch=512,
    f16_kv=True,  # MUST set to True, otherwise you will run into problem after a couple of calls
    callback_manager=callback_manager,
    verbose=True,
    repeat_penalty=1.8
)

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///Chinook.db")

chain = create_sql_query_chain(llm, db)

response = chain.invoke({"question": "How many employees are there"})
print(response)
       
db.run(response)

# Db Chain method

db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, verbose=True)
db_chain.run("How many employees are there?")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).